# Why is there no case agreement between "magni" and "poetae"?

Tags: syntax, declension, adjective, noun, case

Shouldn't "magni" be "magnae" as it is modifying "poetae"?

> Fīliae vestrae dē libris magnī poētae saepe cogitābant.

The quote is from Wheelock's Latin, chapter 6.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is agreement, in fact! Both of these words are masculine genitive singular.

The trick is that *poēta* is a masculine noun, despite being in the first declension. So the genitive singular is *-ae*, just like *puellae*. But agreement depends on gender, not declension, so it takes the masculine *-ī*, just like *puerī*.